# @Specializes in Wildfly 10.1.0

Tags: cdi, java-ee-7, wildfly-10

We are trying to use alternative bean instance injection for our integration test suite deployed on a Wildfly 10.1.0 server.

According to the CDI 1.2 spec, a possible solution to do so would be to use the @Specializes annotation on an alternative deployed in the integration test archive only.

However, the default implementation is always injected. We tried @Specializes on managed beans, session beans, and tried to select the alternatives in the beans.xml file.

The following example illustrate the issue:

BeanInterface.java

```
public interface BeanInterface {
    void work();
}
```

Implementation1.java

```
@Dependent
public class Implementation1 implements BeanInterface {
    @Override
    public void work() {
        System.out.println("test 1");
    }
}
```

Implementation2

```
@Dependent
@Alternative
@Specializes
public class Implementation2 extends Implementation1 {
    @Override
    public void work() {
        System.out.println("test 2");
    }
}
```

TestSingleton.java:

```
@Singleton
@Startup
public class TestSingleton {

    @Inject
    private BeanInterface beanInterface;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        this.beanInterface.work();
    }
}
```

Packaging these classes in a war (with a web.xml) and deploying on wildfly, the implementation 1 is always injected in the Stateless bean.

Wildfly 10.1.0 uses weld-2.3.SP2 which implements CDI 1.2.

Thanks,

Charly

Comment: Did  you declare your bean as an alternative in the beans.xml? Where did you put it? In webapp/WEB-INF? What did you need a web.xml?

Comment: Also, are all of these directly deployed to the WAR, or are there any internal library JARs involved?  As a note, you can automatically activate alternatives via `@Priority`

Comment: Thanks John - Using @Priority on Implementation2 works as expected. We tried that at some point without success , there was probably something else. Rouliboy: I meant a beans.xml, ot web.xml. The beans.xml is empty, with bean-discovery-mode="all".

Comment: @cghislai : if your beans.xml is empty, then `@Alternative` bean is not enabled. You must enable it.

Comment: @rouliboy: There are other ways to select an alternative. The beans.xml is not even necessary in theory with the recent specs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although it does not make the @Specializes annotation work as expected, this solution suggested by John Ament allows to inject the second Implementation.

Just change the @javax.enterprise.inject.Specializes annotation with @javax.annotation.Priority (and some value):

```
@Dependent
@Alternative
@Priority(100)
public class Implementation2 extends Implementation1 {
    @Override
    public void work() {
        System.out.println("test 2");
    }
}
```

Also missing in the OP question was the beans.xml (not web.xml) packaged in the WEB-INF:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
                      http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/beans_1_1.xsd"
    bean-discovery-mode="all">
</beans>
```